# Can't add to lambda Python 3.6

Tags: python

I am trying to create a lambda expression in `Python 3.6` to concatenate a string and `capitalize()` the one of the letters.

The issue I have is that when I try to use a default parameter for one of the arguments, I get an error as below...

```
>>> pt = lambda upper, lower, integer, pat='' : pat=pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda
>>>
```

This is the expression I am trying to run...

`pt = lambda upper, lower, integer, pat='' : pat=pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer`

I did previously have `pat=''` as the first parameter but that caused a syntax error as below...

`SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`

How do I fix this or is it better to use a fully fledged method?

Comment: you need to understand lambda syntax and how it works in Python first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not that you cannot have default arguments in `lambda` functions; you can.

Rather, it is that you are attempting to perform a reassignment *statement* in your `lambda`; namely, `pat=pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer`.

Briefly, a statement is something that doesn't return anything, like `a = 1`, and an expression is something that does `a + 1`.

`lambda` functions do not allow statements, and instead consist of a single expression, whose value is returned.

Accordingly, this will work:

```
pt = lambda upper, lower, integer, pat='' : pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer
```

*However*, it is not something you should be doing anyway, because the whole point of `lambda` functions is that they are throwaway functions you use *once*. If you need to reuse them, just define a free function with `def` instead.

In a project complying with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), this is a style violation.

Comment: So it is just something that is being called with one loop hence why I thought to go with a lambda. It does slowly increment the string though. I assume then as it is being used repeatedly even though it is in one loop only that is still best to build it out into a 'sovereign' function?

Comment: @RichC Yes, in general, the rule is: if you need to name it, then make it a free function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with default value. The following can work (syntactically right):

```
pt = lambda upper, lower, integer, pat='' : pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer
```

This is a good intro to lambda - https://dbader.org/blog/python-lambda-functions

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of :)
Lambda imediately returns so reassigning values in lambda makes no sense.

`pat=pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer`

convert above to:
`pat + upper.capitalize() + lower + integer`

But a general word of advice.
Try not to use lambdas for complex stuff, such as default function arguments etc.
Lambdas are to be used for simple things, for more complex things try to make an inlife function.

you can do:

```
def big_function(x):
  def small_function(x=3):
    return x
  small_function(4)
```